# oracle sql inner join by months

Tags: oracle, inner-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a list of selected accounts and a table of account records (may or may not be in the selected list) across 40 months. I am able to select all the selected accounts that appear at least once in the table, but I also want to see which accounts appear in all 40 months. Like, I am hoping to do something similar to `out join partition by` except I want a smaller set of the data.

How can I do that? Thank you!

example:

```
select distinct table1.acct_no
from table1
inner join selectedAcct
 on table1.acct_no = selectedAcct.acct_no
```

Comment: Please show the table schemas, sample data, and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something lik (not compiled/tested):

```
with acct_month_list as
(
   -- get list of accts/months with missing months
   -- as null
   select distinct a.acctno, m.monno
   from   acctrecs a, mons m
   where  m.monno = a.monno(+)
)
select a2.acctno
from   accounts a2
where not exists ( -- any accounst with a null monno have a missing
                   -- month
                   select null
                   from   acct_month_list al 
                   where  al.acctno = a2.acctno
                   and    a1.monno is null )
and  exists ( -- ignore ones that have no records at all
              select null
              from   acctrecs ar
              where  ar.acctno = a2.acctno )
```